# Substitute of tabulation in web browsers

Tags: browser

It is annoying that double-newline is used to mark a beginning of paragraph in most websites. This happens both because some software strips the leading tabulation (and probably spaces too) and because Tab key is a focus shifter in all browsers which I know.

So, what is a consistent way of indenting paragraphs when writing a text in web browser text field on a random website?

Comment: Are you talking about posting in 'foreign' places like web forums (with limited text fields), or about improving design of _your own_ websites? There are different answers.

Comment: @grawity This is Superuser after all, not SO. :)